# When exactly I have to use State Monad or .copy?

Tags: scala, haskell, scala-cats

I saw an example in a book of haskell in which is created a simple stack (push, pop) and return monad states all the time they update the stack using .put(..) or .pop().

As a reminder the example looks similar to this:

```
pop :: State Stack Int  
pop = State $ \(x:xs) -> (x,xs)  

push :: Int -> State Stack ()  
push a = State $ \xs -> ((),a:xs)
```

It makes sense, but after seeing this example I started to wonder about my domain entities (let's say Customer). For now i'm just using .copy() to return a new updated-Customer everytime i want to update something on it (like the age) like is pointed in many docs, not using any State monad. The way I use .copy() has nothing special:

```
case class Customer(age: Int, name: String) {
   def updateAge(newAge: Int): Customer = {
       this.copy(age = newAge)
   }
}
```

However I'm staring to think that rather than returning just an updated-copy i have to return an State Monad, but I didn't see any example like this so far (I'm learning on my own), and because of that I feel confuse. **I have the impression that .copy() is used sometimes and State Monad is used in other different cases, however both manage State.....**

Should I return an State Monad everytime I update the age of a Customer?

Comment: They are pretty much equivalent.  Look at a small state monad example and expand the definitions away until you can't see any of the State monad vocabulary -- it will look familiar after a little massaging.  It's mainly a matter of style.

Comment: The `State` monad, rather than return a copy of a list, just packages the *actions* you'll take on a value. Once you have the entire chain of actions in one place, you provide an initial stack to get back the final stack. `State` simplifies the type signatures `pop :: Stack -> (Int, Stack)` and `push :: Int -> Stack -> (Stack, ())` and takes care of making sure the same stack returned by one action is pass as an argument to the next action.

Answer (score 12):

You never *have* to return a `State` value—it just makes certain kinds of composition possible, which makes certain ways of building your program cleaner.

For topics like this I think starting from a concrete, clearly motivated example is best, and the [Circe JSON library](https://github.com/circe/circe) includes some `State`-based convenience methods for decoding that I think can help to show how `State` can be useful. For example, suppose we have a Scala case class:

```
case class User(id: Long, name: String, posts: List[Long])
```

We want to be able to decode JSON documents like this:

```
val goodDocument = """{"id": 12345, "name": "Foo McBar", "posts": []}"""
```

But not ones like this:

```
val badDocument =
  """{"id": 12345, "name": "Foo McBar", "posts": [], "bad-stuff": null}"""
```

If we write out a Circe decoder for `User` by hand, it will probably look something like this:

```
implicit val decodeUser: Decoder[User] = Decoder.instance { c =>
  for {
    id    <- c.downField("id").as[Long]
    name  <- c.downField("name").as[String]
    posts <- c.downField("posts").as[List[Long]]
  } yield User(id, name, posts)
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't meet our requirements—it accepts both documents, because it doesn't keep track of what fields have been decoded already and what fields are left over.

```
scala> decode[User](goodDocument)
res0: Either[io.circe.Error,User] = Right(User(12345,Foo McBar,List()))

scala> decode[User](badDocument)
res1: Either[io.circe.Error,User] = Right(User(12345,Foo McBar,List()))
```

We can fix this by keeping track ourselves and "deleting" fields after we see them:

```
import io.circe.{DecodingFailure, Json}

implicit val decodeUser: Decoder[User] = Decoder.instance { c =>
  val idC = c.downField("id")

  def isEmptyObject(json: Json): Boolean = json.asObject.exists(_.isEmpty)

  for {
    id          <- idC.as[Long]
    afterIdC     = idC.delete
    nameC        = afterIdC.downField("name")
    name        <- nameC.as[String]
    afterNameC   = nameC.delete
    postsC       = afterNameC.downField("posts")
    posts       <- postsC.as[List[Long]]
    afterPostsC  = postsC.delete
    _           <- if (afterPostsC.focus.exists(isEmptyObject)) Right(()) else {
      Left(DecodingFailure("Bad fields", c.history))
    }
  } yield User(id, name, posts)
}
```

Which works great!

```
scala> decode[User](goodDocument)
res2: Either[io.circe.Error,User] = Right(User(12345,Foo McBar,List()))

scala> decode[User](badDocument)
res3: Either[io.circe.Error,User] = Left(DecodingFailure(Bad fields, List()))
```

But the code is a mess, since we have to interleave our logic for keeping track of what's been used through our nice clean `Decoder.Result`-based `for`-comprehension.

The way Circe supports decoders that keep track of what fields have been used is based on Cats's `StateT`. Using these helper methods, you can write the following:

```
import cats.instances.either._

implicit val decodeUser: Decoder[User] = Decoder.fromState(
  for {
    id    <- Decoder.state.decodeField[Long]("id")
    name  <- Decoder.state.decodeField[String]("name")
    posts <- Decoder.state.decodeField[List[Long]]("posts")
    _     <- Decoder.state.requireEmpty
  } yield User(id, name, posts)
)
```

This looks a lot like our original (non-used-field-tracking) implementation, but it works exactly the same way as our second implementation.

We can look at the type of a single operation:

```
scala> Decoder.state.decodeField[String]("name")
res4: StateT[Decoder.Result,ACursor,String] = ...
```

Which is a kind of wrapper for the following:

```
ACursor => Decoder.Result[(ACursor, Long)]
```

This is basically combining the `afterIdC.downField("name")`, `nameC.delete`, and `nameC.as[String]` lines from our verbose implementation above, but encapsulating them in a single operation that we can use in a `for`-comprehension.

Calling `copy` on a case class to get an updated value is of course perfectly fine, and most of the time it's exactly what you want. You shouldn't complicate your code with `State` unless you're sure it's adding value, and it's most likely to add value when you find yourself threading calls to `copy` and assignments through some other kind of operation, like we saw with field-use tracking and decoding above.